# Re-running DMA transfer from ADC to memory on STM32F429

Tags: stm32, dma, stm32f4discovery, adc

I have DMA2 stream 0 configured so that it transfers given number of samples from ADC3 (triggered by TIM2 rising edge) to memory, and after completing the  transfer an interrupt happens in which I make calculations on the samples gathered.

Everything is working as intented, except that I would like to be able to repeat the whole process. Transfer should be started by user command (button press, or eventually by command send through USART), therefore I can't use DMA in circular mode for this task.

From what I've found, it is possible to re-run the transfer by modifying some registers and restarting the DMA and ADC, yet I was unable to complete the task. What is the correct set of instructions I have to run to achieve my goal?